# Proper updating of a 32bit method to 64bit support

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a method I am trying to update to 64-bit support for my app. I have lots of these `warnings`.

The issue is with the below example. I get the warning:

***Implicit conversion loses integer precision NSInteger to int***

```
- (int)  aMethod {
    NSUserDefaults *u = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    return [u integerForKey:@"someKey"];
}
```

If I change the return type to `NSInteger` I get

***Conflicting return type in implementation of aMethod int vs NSInteger aka long***

```
-(NSInteger)  aMethod {
    NSUserDefaults *u = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    return [u integerForKey:@"someKey"];
}
```

I have tried casting the return type

`return (NSInteger)[u integerForKey:@"someKey"];`

or

`return (long)[u integerForKey:@"someKey"];`

But I can't get the error to go away unless I cast it to (int)

`return (int)[u integerForKey:@"someKey"];`

I have read many SO questions but I can't seem to get a good answer.

**What is the proper way of updating this method?**

Comment: When you use `-(NSInteger)  aMethod {`, do you update the signature in the .h file too?  (...or any other place it's declared.)

Comment: You're right. I forgot to update my .h files *facepalm*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method:

```
- (int) aMethod ...
```

returns a value of type `int`. The method may first declared, probably in a header (`.h`) file, and then defined in an implementation (`.m`) file.

The statement:

```
return [u integerForKey:@"someKey"];
```

returns the result of calling `integerForKey:`, which is a value of type `NSInteger`.

`NSInteger` is not a type defined by the (Objective-)C *language*, rather it is a *type alias* (`typedef`) defined in the *frameworks* intended to represent the "natural" integer size on the platform. It is an alias for `int` on 32-bit platforms and `long` on 64-bit.

So your compiler error is telling you that the (now) 64-bit value is being truncated to fit a 32-bit result. There is no single right way to fix this, it depends on what the use of the value associated with `@someKey` is:

- If the value should now be 64-bit then change the return type of `aMethod`; both in its separate declaration, if it has one, and in its implementation; to `NSInteger`. You will also need to check that wherever the method is called that returning an `NSInteger` value is acceptable, and you may need to make follow-on changes to variable types etc. You also need to look at places where the value associated with the key is set.
- If the value associated with the key may remain as 32-bit then you can use `intForKey:` instead of `integerForKey` and leave the return type as is. You should also change where the key is set to store an `int`

HTH

**Correction**

There is (no longer?) a convenience method `intForKey:` on `NSUserDefaults`. Alternatives include: `integerForKey:` and casting; `objectForKey:` to obtain an `NSNumber` reference and then `intValue`; etc.